# Advantage to Git LFS when large files don't change?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm considering using Git LFS for a repository that will contain ISO and installer files that are used by our system image build tools (in this case Packer). We'll then add it as a submodule of our main repo that has the build scripts so it can be integrated into our CI toolchain.

As I understand Git LFS, the large files are replaced with a pointer so repo pulls and maintenance are quick and then the files are downloaded over a different channel.

However, when we add the files they'll have the version number in the name so they won't need to be updated (e.g. `ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso`). They also won't need to be removed because we'll reference specific versions by that full name in build scripts. We'll basically always be adding and rarely (if ever) updating or deleting.

It seems like Git LFS is mainly for updating / deleting. Are there any remaining technical advantages for our use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *It seems like Git LFS is mainly for updating / deleting.*

Git-LFS is mostly to keep the repository size down. `git clone` normally downloads the entire repository, so `git-lfs` mostly affects `clone`. The repository includes all files and all versions of those files, ***including the deleted ones***.

If you make a minor Ubuntu update and `git rm ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso` and `git add ubuntu-16.04.5-server-amd64.iso` now you're storing two ISOs. Another update and it's three. Then four. Five. Six. Without `git-lfs`, everyone has to download and store all of those old deleted ISOs.

If you're going to store large files like Operating System ISOs or media files they will rapidly bloat the size of the repository. This means anyone cloning your repository will have to spend the time and bandwidth to download everything, and spend disk space on everything. This bloats your development process and makes people hesitant to download a 20 gig repository just to work on a few text files.

> *Are there any remaining technical advantages for our use case?*

Yes. There's little cost to using `git-lfs`. That cost is lowest if you use it sooner rather than later.

You can use `git-lfs` later, but there's some strings attached. If you use it on existing files they'll be in `git-lfs` going forward, but their old versions will still be in history. You can [use the BFG to rewrite history to retroactively put existing large files into `git-lfs`](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5), but rewriting your entire history is not something you want to be doing often. You should probably use `git-lfs` sooner rather than later.

[Here is a good run-down about what it takes to switch over later](https://vooban.com/en/tips-articles-geek-stuff/migrating-to-git-lfs-for-developing-deep-learning-applications-with-large-files/).

Using `git-lfs` early means developers don't have to think hard about whether to put something into the repository just because it's too big. If there's something they feel should be in version control they put it in version control, regardless of size. This simplifies the developer's decision making process and makes for a healthier repository. If you need to, say, have six different Operating System ISOs in the repository for testing they can do that without a debate about repository bloat.

It also means you don't have to do work arounds to account for repository bloat. There are various means to only clone part of a repository, but they all add complexity. There are means to let Git store compressed ISOs and archives more efficiently, you unpack them and let Git store them as normal files, but again that adds complexity. `git-lfs` means you can keep things simple(r).

Finally, the storage side of `git-lfs` is flexible. You're not beholden to Github or any particular Git site for LFS storage.

Answer (score 4):

Only the current files used in your branch will be downloaded from git lfs. The files from other branches or commits in the past will not be downloaded.

If you put all in the standard git repo everything will always be cloned, including the deleted big files *which are* in the history.

Thus git lfs will allow you faster to work on your build server as less time is required for cloning and downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it would also be an easy way to ensure those dependencies are available at all times without relying on an another tool.